# Assign pointer A to B. After I free A, B still exist

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

If I declare pointer ***A and ***B, allocate memory to A, and say "B = A", 
I need to free only "A", right?
Why I can still read stuffs when I call B[1][1][1]?

The codes are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../Toolbox/3DArray.c"

int main(void)
{
  double ***P1, ***P2;
  P1 = d_3DArray(2, 2, 2);

  P2 = P1;

  int i, j, k;
  for(i=1; i<=2; i++){
    for(j=1; j<=2; j++){
      for(k=1; k<=2; k++){
    P1[i][j][k] = k + 10*j + 100*i;
      }}}


  free_d_3DArray(P1);

  if(P2 == NULL) printf("P2 becomes a NULL pointer. \n");
  else printf("P2[1][1][1] = %.0lf \n", P2[1][1][2]);


  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
P2[1][1][1] = 112
```

which is exactly the value assigned by the for loop.
`free_d_3DArray` is like this:

```
void free_d_3DArray(double ***x)
{
  free(x[0][0]);
  free(x[0]);
  free(x);
}
```

But if I put `free_d_3DArray(P2);` as well, I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". 

What should I do??

Thanks for any reply!

**Update**
Thank you all for the replies. I understand it now. I am sorry for this silly question (>u<)

Comment: `free`ing something will - as it were - _free_ up that memory to be used reallocated and used elsewhere. That doesn't mean it will immediately be used and rewritten, though it could be, so it's possible the old data will remain, but you're accessing it an "unsafe" or "unpredictable" way. As a rule of thumb, do one `free` for each `malloc` you do.

Comment: You do not free a pointer, but the object it points to. Note that accessing `free`d objectsw invokes _undefined behaviour_ (think about the implications of the first word!). Do you see any [nasal daemons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) already? You do not use a 3D array. That only requires a single star. Also note that being a three-star programmer is not a compliment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `free_d_3DArray` is not freeing *all* of the memory. You may wish to add the `d_3DArray` function to the question, to get some advice on how to properly free the memory.  After calling `free_d_3DArray`, neither `P1` nor `P2` will be `NULL`. If you want them to be `NULL`, you have to set them to `NULL` yourself. And, the `printf` has a typo, `P2[1][1][2]` is out of bounds for the array and will cause undefined behavior, whether or not the array was previously freed.

Comment: @Olaf: The undefined behavior starts *before* dereferencing. `if(P2 == NULL) ` is undefined.

Comment: @EOF: Can you point me where the standard states that? `P2` is not dereferenced.

Comment: @Olaf: C11 draft standard, `6.2.4 Storage durations of objects 2 [...]The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.[...]`, Annex `J.2 Undefined behavior [...]The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate [...]`.

Comment: @EOF: Hmm.. good point. I'm still not sure if this applies to a comparison with a _null pointer_, but as such construct is useless anyway, I will accept your claim. Thanks for the citations.

Comment: @Olaf: No, I've never heard of nasal daemons. Thank you for the information and for telling me not to be a 3-star programmer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
P2 = P1;
free_d_3DArray(P1);
if(P2 == NULL) ...
```

`P2` will never be null because it has the value that P1 had. Freeing P1 does not change that. If the value of P1 changes, then that does not reflect in P2. That is the "hard" part of C; you have to do everything yourself; the compiler will not do anything more than compile your statements.

That you still can find valid values in P2 is because, although the memory has been returned to the heap for re-use, the heap manager does not have to zero the memory or so. Hence you may still see valid values, as long as the memory is not re-used somewhere else by your program.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `free`, memory which was allocated can be used once again by another variable or anything else. That doesn't mean it is used at the same moment. If you call pointer to the place where your variable was, it may still be there. It may not too.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `free` doesn't mean that the freed up memory is also initialized to zero or anything else,
but calling a freed up pointer leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you free a pointer the allocation of the pointer is freed, the value in the memory for the variable doesn't change because of that. It changes when you overwrite to it.

when you copy the value of the pointer from A to B, you copy the memory address from A to B, and then when you free A, you only free the place where the address in A is written, but B still holds the address.